# Tensorflow-gpu is not working in basic text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have

- `tensorflow==2.3.0;`
- `tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0`
- `CUDA==10.1`
- `cuDNN==7.6.5`

I tried to train a neural network following the example https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification.

To enable the GPU, I added the following code

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

just before

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

In this example, the GPU is working! But in another example https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification
when I add the session connection before

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1)])
```

the GPU doesn't work.

What do I need to do to get the GPU for the second example?

Comment: What does "the GPU doesn't work" mean? How exactly are you determining that?

Comment: How can you say GPU is not working?

Comment: I meant that the video card is not used to train the neural network.